# iPhone / iPad CalDav Debugging

Tags: java, iphone, ipad, caldav

I've build and application that uses caldav in Java. It works fine with iCal and other CalDav client but I can't seem to get it to work on iphone/ipad. The consol debugger in xCode is not very explicite about what the problem is. Is there any tool around to help me debug what my application is doing wrong?

More information. The server side is running Java with a servlet and tomcat. The client side is the Apple Caldav support on iphone / ipad. I use xcode to see the consol of the phone. I get error codes like: DAVErrorDomain/30. What ever that means it somewhere but I can't find any good info about apple's error codes anywhere. Any idea?

Comment: Can you add some more detail? Is your application sending data over through an API, and the client isn't getting it properly? You can't run a Java application on the iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch, like Angel said.

Comment: Without context, this is extremely difficult to answer objectively.

Answer (score -1):

The iPad/iPhone does not support Java, so likely XCode is complaining about this fact?

Comment: I guess Alex is using Java on the server side and the iPad / iPhone as a client.